# Moving summing block before integrator

Tags: filter, control-system, low-pass

I wanted to move the summing operation (+10) that I perform before the integrator block as shown below: (MODEL-1)
[image]

I check in this wikibook page - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Block_Diagrams and from the transformation "Moving a Summing Junction in front of a Block", it says to add a 1/P block, which in this case would be a differentiator. I tried adding a differentiator block like below, but the outputs (taken @ every 100th clock cycle) of the blocks does not match. (MODEL-2)

[image]

The output from MODEL-1 is:

[image]

The output from MODEL-2 is:

[image]

This is one part of this question.

However the major part is, when using this filter practically, the input to this filter contains high-frequency noise(now - just for example, it contains a pure sinusoid). By adding a differentiator in the front for the purpose of transformation dissolve the whole purpose of filtering?

Comment: Where do you want to add this offset? To From3 usually for a single polarity signal source to make it bipolar, you subtract a positive offset to make  the input to the discrete transform bipolar.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I want to move this offset(+10) to the beginning of the integrator block.

Comment: I don’t see a single integrator block

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 \$\frac{z}{z - 1}\$ is the integration operator in the Z domain. I suppose properly it's called the "accumulation" operator due to being a discrete-time thing, but people call it integration anyway.

Comment: @Hearth  so at DC where offset is applied to the input , is it an integrator?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Yes. Are you unfamiliar with the Z-transform? It's the discrete-time analog of the Laplace transform, and \$\frac{z}{z - 1}\$ (sometimes equivalently written as \$\frac{1}{1 - z^{-1}}\$) is the Z-transform's analog to \$\frac{1}{s}\$ in the Laplace domain. The reason it's not just \$\frac{1}{z}\$ has to do with the way the Z-transform is defined.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZx8E.jpg No I’ve never had the pleasure to work with DSP’s or Z domain, but I understand it is often used to prevent overflow and remove DC, but I wonder why the OP wants to add DC offset.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The purpose of adding DC offset is a part of linearization after filtering. But anyways, the image that you added - what does it show?

Comment: It shows how to block DC and prevent sigma delta overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're so far off I'm not even going to attempt fixing your thinking.  This.  And I hope I'm not doing your homework.  Note that this won't work in real life because it's causing a pole-zero cancellation of a metastable pole.

[image]

Comment: IMO this is useless, however it is correctly moved to obtain the same result and that's what's OP is asking for (maybe? He is also confused). But unfortunatelly this won't work, because the integration goes to infinity. Integratring a constant brings you always to a dead end.

Comment: It's not integrating a constant!  It's integrating the *derivative* of a constant!  So everything is ok!  Something that I should have perhaps pointed out is that the whole block diagram manipulation thing is really just a way to do math with blocks; as soon as you start moving the blocks in the diagram away from the structure of the physical system they represent, you lose meaning.  You may gain an easy path to solving for a transfer function, but you need to keep in mind that you've massacred the physical sense of the diagram.